# Is there a PowerShell code formatter / pretty printer?

Tags: powershell, pretty-print

I'm looking for a source code beautifyer for PowerShell programs. Ideally, it would be CLI based, but any solution is acceptable. I would like to avoid configuring a generic pretty printer tool; I'd like a solution that works for PowerShell out of the box. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Try Visual Studio Code with Powershell Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell

Comment: @live-love are you saying that extension has code formatting? It doesn't mention that anywhere?

Answer (score 34):

UPDATE: it's now on GitHub: https://github.com/DTW-DanWard/PowerShell-Beautifier

I wrote a PowerShell pretty printer / code cleaner in PowerShell.  It cleans white space, indents code groups, replaces aliases with commands, fixes casing on commands, parameters, types, etc.  You can use it to reformat a file in place or read a source file and output the result in a different file.

More info: 
http://danspowershellstuff.blogspot.com/2012/03/powershell-pretty-printer-code-cleaner.html

Download page:
http://www.dtwconsulting.com/PS/Module_PrettyPrinterV1.htm

Let me know what you'd like to see changed/configurable/etc.

Comment: YES! You awesome guy you!

Comment: Have you considered porting your code to GitHub so others can contribute?

Comment: Yep - I've been working on cleaning it up and completing test files and documentation.  Should be up in the next few days.

Comment: It's now on GitHub: [https://github.com/DTW-DanWard/PowerShell-Beautifier](https://github.com/DTW-DanWard/PowerShell-Beautifier)

Comment: I cannot get this to work for the life of me.  Can you provide better instructions.   I downloaded the source now what?

Comment: Backup/commit your PowerShell file first or practice on a test copy! Assume your file is: c:\Temp\TestFile.ps1
Open PowerShell Window
Import-Module C:\Temp\PowerShell-Beautifier\src\DTW.PS.Beautifier.psd1
(Takes a few seconds the first time.)
Edit-DTWBeautifyScript c:\Temp\TestFile.ps1
This cleans file in place, overwriting orig copy (thus the need for the backup or commit first).  Or you can:
Edit-DTWBeautifyScript c:\Temp\TestFile.ps1 c:\Temp\CleanFile.ps1
Outputs the results to a new file, leaving the first untouched.
https://github.com/DTW-DanWard/PowerShell-Beautifier#usage

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any. However, PowerShell V2 exposes a PowerShell tokenizer you could build on: `System.Management.Automation.PsParser`

It might be interesting to do some "lint"-like checks, too.

For example, I think scripts should avoid using aliases that aren't marked `ReadOnly`, as users may have changed them. See [Where are the default aliases defined in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770526/where-are-the-default-aliases-defined-in-powershell/2816523#2816523) for some discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ScriptCop](http://scriptcop.start-automating.com/).
Props to [Mike Shepard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36429/mike-shepard) - I found this from his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720861/looking-for-a-code-analysis-tool-for-powershell/6619197#6619197).