# PowerShell Code Tidy or Reformat?

Tags: powershell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a PowerShell code formatter / pretty printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987176/is-there-a-powershell-code-formatter-pretty-printer)

Does anyone know of a tool that you can use to re-format/tidy Powershell code:-

Eg:-

```
if ($c -eq "Cat") 
{
$a="Bubble" 
}
else
{
$a="Trouble"
}
Write-Host $a
```

To:-

```
if ($c -eq "Cat") 
{
    $a="Bubble" 
}
else
{
    $a="Trouble"
}
Write-Host $a
```

ie, tabbing If Statements etc, I know they was tools to do it with VB but I haven't seen any for Powershell yet?

Comment: Gary, you've lost all your formatting in your question, please use the code tags in your question with the provided code tags.

Answer (score 8):

Quick update - it's now on GitHub: https://github.com/DTW-DanWard/PowerShell-Beautifier
I wrote a PowerShell pretty printer / code cleaner in PowerShell.  It cleans white space, indents code groups, replaces aliases with commands, fixes casing on commands, parameters, types, etc.  You can use it to reformat a file in place or read a source file and output the result in a different file.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987176

Answer (score 7):

A quick test with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) indicates the `TextFX-> TextFX Edit -> Reindent C++` macro works as desired on your example.  No idea how well it handles more complex samples.

Also of note, NP++ has a language formatting macro for PowerShell.  Somewhat unexpectedly, the PowerGui Script Editor does not seem to have a tidy function.

Answer (score 2):

A quick doodle that works with your code:

```
$tab = '  '
$indent = 0

switch -regex -file ./x.ps1 {
  '{\s*$'   { $tab * $indent++ + $_ }
  '^\s*}'   { $tab * --$indent + $_ }
  '^\s*$'   { "" }
  '[^{}]'   { $tab * $indent + $_ }
}
```

No guarantees for reliability. It might do weird things with code that makes heavy use of single-line blocks or closes a block not in a separate line. But apart from that it might work.

Answer (score 2):

If you use gvim (and [powershell plugins](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1815)) you can easily indent all line of your code whenever you want, by typing (when you are in command mode):
`gg=G`

Answer (score 0):

It may be tough to find a windows version of it, but check out http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/ .  It can probably handle powershell code quite nicely.

Comment: You can find windows versions of it..  http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/