# PowerShell script in one long line - auto-format?

Tags: powershell, code-cleanup

I was given a PowerShell script, that when opened in a text editor, is one **very** long line of code.  Is there any kind of auto-format tool for PowerShell syntax?  I use Notepad++ and read a thread here (https://superuser.com/questions/58884/auto-format-document-with-notepad)and here ([PowerShell Code Tidy or Reformat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807943/powershell-code-tidy-or-reformat)) about certain plugins that can help with indentation and other code cleanup, but nothing that I've seen that can take one long line and tidy it.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use VSCode `vscode-powershell` plugin or so? And also, if you can, please share that long line of code as text here -to make sure if it is a string or a very long command etc.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns this does not work to auto-format the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using `Visual Studio Code` with the `PowerShell` extension.  From there, you can utilize the `Format Document` tool (default keybind: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>).  This will look at your settings file and uses `PSScriptAnalyzer` to perform the formatting rules.

With the newest update (June2018), `Visual Studio Code` supports fully portable downloads by downloading the `.zip` option and creating the `/data/tmp/` directory in the root where `code.exe` lives.

- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
- [PowerShell extension releases](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/releases)
- [Microsoft recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/vscode/using-vscode?view=powershell-5.1)