# PowerShell code formatting

Tags: powershell, optimization, conventions

I'm relatively new to PowerShell. I started learning language few weeks ago. I'm struggling with tooling a little bit. I'm responsible for pretty big legacy project written in PowerShell which I need to support. Since there were no coding conventions required before, code doesn't look very nice :-) and it makes it pretty hard to understand. 

Since I originally come from Java world, one thing I'm used to, is **IDE support for automatic code formatting**. However, ISE nor Visual Studio 2013 (community edition) does not seem to support this feature. 


Can you please advise how can I reformat my PowerShell code automatically? Thank you.

Matthew

Comment: You can look at the answers given in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987176/is-there-a-powershell-code-formatter-pretty-printer

Comment: Thanks, I read that thread before. However, I was hoping that there's some 'official' tooling from Microsoft for this purpose. I guess PowerShell is not that far yet ... :-/. Perhaps it's best to gradually rewrite my scripts one by one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a PowerShell code formatter / pretty printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987176/is-there-a-powershell-code-formatter-pretty-printer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you are using a third party product to write your Java code? There is a third party product that can reformat PowerShell automatically: http://www.sapien.com/blog/2014/06/10/powershell-studio-2014-code-formatting/

Comment: Well, it's pretty simple formatter, I imagined more capabilities, but it got basic job done :-). Thank you.

Comment: I hope it works faster than rewriting all of your scripts one by one :-) You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Code with [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) can do this (very simple)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a big legacy project (many files) and you don't want to reformat each one in the IDE, you can use this: https://github.com/DTW-DanWard/PowerShell-Beautifier

It's written in PowerShell and works in the pipeline so you can run it on a folder recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Expounding on smg's answer (I have too few reputation points to comment), you can use the Format Document (Shift+Alt+F) command in VS Code.

It's explained in more detail here: [Auto Formatting PowerShell in Visual Studio Code](https://dscottraynsford.wordpress.com/2017/11/18/auto-formatting-powershell-in-visual-studio-code/)